# Sketchup STL to Blender clean up mesh

Tags: mesh

[image]
Import an STL created in Sketchup.
[image]
Edit mode the mesh looks a mess.
[image]
How can I clean up the mesh so it is just one piece so I can subdivide it and work on it with textures.
Thanks.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/171165/how-can-i-improve-my-mesh-imported-from-sketchup?rq=1

Comment: limited dissolve: x l